# How to fold a sequence with a writer monad embedding a disjunction using combinators?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm making some computation that may fail, so I'm using a disjunction type as result. I have a fairly common pattern for which I've written the following function :

```
def traverse[A, B, E](a: Iterable[A], b: B)(f: (B, A) => E \/ B): E \/ B =
    a.foldLeft[E\/B](\/-(b)){case (b0, a0) => b0 flatMap (f(_, a0))}
```

But now I want to log the computation (both in case of failure or success). I need a function with the following type :

```
type Logged[T] = scalaz.Writer[String,T]
def traverseLogged[A, B, E]
       ( a: Iterable[A], lb: Logged[B])
       ( f: (Logged[B], A) => Logged[E \/ B]): Logged[E \/ B]
```

However I cannot find a "nice implementation" relying on combinators. I've come up with the following implementation :

```
a.foldLeft[Logged[E \/ B]](lb.map(_.right[E])){
  (lb0, a0) =>
    val (log, value) = lb0.run
    value match {
      case -\/(err) => lb0
      case \/-(b) => f(b.set(log),a0)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to implement it without having to run the logged b ?

PS: I hope the question title is clear enough >_<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it's worth noting that your `traverse` is essentially `foldLeftM`. `foldLeftM` works on things with a `Foldable` instance, which doesn't include `Iterable`, but I'd suggest avoiding `Iterable` anyway when working with Scalaz.

So you can just write:

```
a.foldLeftM[({ type L[x] = E \/ x })#L, B](b)(f)
```

Or:

```
type MyErrorOr[A] = MyError \/ A

a.foldLeftM[MyErrorOr, B](b)(f)
```

In the `Writer` case I'd suggest not building up a `Writer` value in the accumulator. Instead you can use the `EitherT` monad transformer:

```
type StringWriter[A] = Writer[String, A]
type LoggedOr[E, A] = EitherT[StringWriter, E, A]
```

Now you can use `foldLeftM` again:

```
def traverseLogged[A, B, E](a: List[A], b: B)(
  f: (B, A) => LoggedOr[E, B]
): LoggedOr[E, B] = a.foldLeftM[({ type L[x] = LoggedOr[E, x] })#L, B](b)(f)(
  EitherT.eitherTMonad[StringWriter, E]
)
```

(To be honest I'm not sure why you have to provide the monad instance explicitly here—it'd work just fine if we had a type alias for our `LoggedOr` with a fixed `E`.)

Now when you run the result you'll get a `Writer[String, E \/ B]`, which is the same as in your original `traverseLogged`. You could actually do that in the method and return a `Logged` directly, but it might be useful to stay at the level of `LoggedOr` if you need to compose multiple actions like this.

This assumes that you don't actually need access to the accumulated `Writer` in `f`, but if you did, that would suggest that another type would probably be more appropriate, anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I was sure that my "traverse" was already in scalaz but I didn't manage to find it.
For the traverseLogged, I need to thread the log during the fold so I cannot use directly your solution. However you gave me something nice to chew. I'm going to look further into it tomorrow. (It's a bit late here)
Again, thank you very much !

Comment: Ok I looked into it again with a fresh mind. I managed to implement pretty much my "traverseLogged" with yours : 
http://pastebin.com/Mc9Lr6dN
However all these change of levels seems a bit weird. Actually my type B is a graph and I do some transformations (that may fail). But the tricky part is that some of these transformations can be mutually recursive, so I kind of need to change of level. Are these level changes normal, or do I need to look more into functions of the lift family (still a scalaz newbie :p) or do I have to make a custom type, a monad mixing disjunction and writer ?